# Filtering for a SharePoint field

Tags: filter

How do I filter records so that only records that are not blank for a particular field show? I only want records displayed that have a value for a particular field.

Comment: How do you need this? In view or programmatically? if programmatically, then specify the language like C# or javascript

Comment: Thanks! Since its a text field I had to use the filter and add the conditions for the vowels and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a view for this this

[image]